# How to SFTP with Github Actions?

Tags: github, sftp, github-actions

I want to use Github actions to transfer files to a remote server via SFTP (only option for this server) when I push up to Github.

I am using this Action https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-deploy

I have created a file in my repo in `.github/workflows/main.yml` and I have added:

```
on: push
name: Publish Website
jobs:
  FTP-Deploy-Action:
    name: FTP-Deploy-Action
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      with:
        fetch-depth: 2
    - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
      with:
        ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
        ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
        ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

I have created a Secret for this repo which contains the following:

```
FTP_SERVER: sftp.server.com, FTP_USERNAME: user, FTP_PASSWORD: password
```

I can see the action running in Github but it errors out on the `FTP-Deploy-Action` task.

> ##[error]Input required and not supplied: ftp-server

This is in secrets and does work with Filezilla.

Would anyone know if I've set this up wrongly?

Comment: Can you try using the raw server url, username and password (instead of secrets) to see if the error goes away? One common issue with SFTP via github action is the prompt to accept server certificate. You can bypass that using `git-ftp-args: --insecure`

Comment: Yes @manishg hardcoding the values worked. I wonder why Secrets doesnt

Comment: Any clue in your actions log?

Comment: Please note that sftp support has been removed with version 4.0. See [SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action Release Notes](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/releases) for details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get it working on my own repo. I think the issue may be possibly on how your secrets were setup. That error usually shows when required parameters of a github action were not provided so curious if the keys are different or whether they were saved as empty. I would delete `FTP_SERVER` secret and create it again to be sure.

[Workflow Success Run](https://github.com/meroware/ftp-workflow-example/runs/1059806151)

[Workflow Code](https://github.com/meroware/ftp-workflow-example/blob/b18a0b92b11951dfc572cc69aa5c01d4c6c40658/.github/workflows/ftp.yaml#L9)

```
  - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
    uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
    with:
      ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
      ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
      ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
      local-dir: toupload
```

**UPDATE:** Added example per comment left below,

Example secret creation for reference. Basically create a secret per entry rather than comma separated grouped secret

[image]

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets

Comment: Very odd. Just curious: how are your secretes set up? Are the comma seperated like mine above? On new lines?

Comment: It’s one secret per entry. Meaning, the secret name is FTP_SERVER and the value using your example would be sftp.server.com Then repeat the same with the other two secrets. I updated the response above so you can see the secret created for FTP_SERVER

Comment: Ohh! I thought they were a set of key and value pairs! Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 5 with SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1 and the same keys you've provided? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: @realarb place git-ftp-args: --insecure behind ftp-password param in you .yml file

Comment: Does the recent version also support sftp? I get timeout errors. Do I need to explicitly set the protocol option? https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action

Comment: I get The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 8

Answer (score 3):

I tried a lot but SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action did not work for me. Finally  I found an alternative solution that does:

```
- name: deploy
  uses: pressidium/lftp-mirror-action@v1
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.SFTP_URL }}
    port: ${{ secrets.SFTP_PORT }}
    user: ${{ secrets.SFTP_USER }}
    pass: ${{ secrets.SFTP_PASSWORD }}
    localDir: './toupload'
    remoteDir: '.'
    reverse: true
```